# CUDAResourcesInformation Issue during CUDA setup

Tags: cudalink, cuda

I am trying to set up CUDA on a Windows 10/64 bit machine with a NVIDIA GeFore GTX 1080 with Max-Q Design running Mathematica Version 12.3.

I have issued the following commands:

```
 Needs["CUDALink`]
 CUDAQ[]
 CUDAInformation[]
 CUDADRiverVersion[]
```

In response to CUDAQ[] the system returns True and CUDAInformation[] returns a list of parameters describing the capabilities of my system: (ie {1 -> {Name -> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 with Max-Q design, .... Total Memory -> 8489737984}.  CUDADiverVersion[] returns 496.13.

However, when I try executing the command

```
 CUDAResourcesInformation[]
```

It returns an error indicated that "CUDAResources was not found.  Make sure that you are connected to the internet and Mathematica is allowed access to the internet."

Mathematica is able to link to the internet (eg. "Hyperlink["https://nvidia.com/getcuda"] works just fine.

```
Likewise,

CUDADot[Table[i, {i, 10}, {j, 10}], Table[i, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]]
```

or

```
CUDAMap[Cos,RandomReal[1,100]]
```

also give me the same error, indicating that something is not set up properly.

also does not work, but rather indicates again that CUDAResources was not found.

It appears that all is not working as it should be.  What needs to be done to get CUDA working properly?

Comment: Edit -> Preferences : Can your installation [connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUp2m.png) to the WRI servers?

Comment: Are the CUDADriverVersion at the latest state? I can recall similar issue at my installation once and I thing it had something to do with the Cuda driver installation and the version of driver the GPU supports.

Comment: Yes, the Edit-Preferences-Internet & Mail Test Internet Connectivity successfully passes.  Just downloaded the drivers yesterday, I believe version 496.13 of the CUDA driver is the latest version.

Comment: Have you installed the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit as specified in the [CUDALink Setup](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html) tutorial. I think starting in one of the 12.x versions Wolfram stopped including this and requires the user to install it.  Follow the other steps in the setup tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

According to WR `CUDAResources[]` and `CUDAResourcesInformation[]`  are obsolete in Version 12.3.  Eisbar's suggestion seems to be correct.

CUDADriverVersion 496.49 works with Version 12.3, at least on my machine.

Comment: PacletUpdate["CUDAResources"] installs 14.0.211